# jQuery/HTML5 roulette not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a jquery/html5 roulette into my site.
I've found some jsfiddle code I'd like to use: http://jsfiddle.net/kYvzd/118/
But when I'm trying to implement it on my website it won't work..
I'm receiving the error TypeError: $(...).spinwheel is not a function
[Learn More]

This is the code I've implemented: 
The HTML:

```
<legend class="text-center header">Roulette!</legend>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="left-column">
      <form class="iform" action="#" method="get">
        <label for="joiner"></label>
        <input id="joiner" name="joiner" class="joiner" placeholder="Please Enter your name" />
        <button class="add">Add</button>
        <button class="spin-trigger">Spin</button>
      </form>        
      <canvas class="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas> 
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
      <p class="winner">The Winner is ... <span>&nbsp;</span></p>
      <ul class="participants">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.canvas').spinwheel({
       pplArray : ["♈", "♉", "♊", "♋","♌", "♍", "♎", "♏","♐", "♑", "♒", "♓"]
   });
});
</script>
```

The JS is exactly as the JS file, implemented like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php
  if($active=="roulette") echo '<script src="js/roulette.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
?>
```

I can see that the file is roulette.js is implemented, so there's nothing wrong at the PHP part $active.
I feel really stupid because I've basically just copied the code and it won't work..
And the `<script>` part in the HTML that's the only thing I've moved because I will need to change some values there dynamically.

**Update:** 
The website link is: http://randomstock.net/roulette.php

Comment: jquery 1.6 is very old. Maybe roulette.js does something that is unsupported by this version - try jquery 1.9 or jquery 3

Comment: The jsfiddle is running jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 2):

You have two copies of jQuery included in your site. Looking at the `<head>` you have

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/roulette.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

At this point, you have jQuery 1.6 running on the page, with the spinwheel plugin added to jQuery as you are expecting.

You have the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("canvas").spinwheel(...);
});
```

This would all work as you are expecting.

**HOWEVER!**

Towards the bottom of your page, you have

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At this point, you have a new copy of jQuery - one without the spinwheel plugin installed. Your page is in a weird limbo state, where the `$(document).ready` is running from jQuery 1.6, but the `$` inside it when it runs will be the newer jQuery, without the plugin.

Two solutions:

1. Preferred: get rid of the duplicate jQuery
2. `$(document).ready(function($) { ... })` will ensure that the `$` inside the function will be the same as the one outside.

Comment: Third option would be to use [nonconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). I would still prefer option 1.